# Small enigne ECU self development

Tags: automotive-engineering

Has anyone used Freescale's (now NXP semiconductors) small engine ECU development kit? If so, please give me pointers on which model to choose to tune a 50cc Yamaha GY6 engine. Also as I'm still in college will the difficulty be too high ( i.e, would I require High level knowledge).

Comment: Never used one before, but this one? [NXP Single Cycliner ECU](http://www.nxp.com/products/discretes-and-logic/mosfets/low-side-switches/reference-design-mc33812-s12p-small-engine-control:KIT33812ECUEVME) Check out the reference design manual PDF. Looks like there are some guides on how to set it up. It's probably not "easy" to do. IMO, there are no baby steps with these things, you've got to dive in head first. That GY6 looks carbureted, are you trying to convert to EFI? Please be more spcific with your question.

Comment: As it stands, this question is far too broad. The best kinds of question for our site are those that have definitive answers, whereas this is more of a discussion, and a "correct" answer would essentially be an entire user manual. If you can narrow it down to one or two specific questions about using this kit, it might be re-opened. (It is worth noting that some users also identified this as off-topic, regardless of question quality.)